# Is it appropriate to say "When it was my birthday"?

Tags: time-reference

Is it appropriate to say:

> "When it was my birthday..."

when speaking about my childhood, for instance when I want to say what I used to do, eat and things like that? I had always thought it was until a friend of mine told me it is not.

Comment: In what context? The _usual_ expression would be 'on my birthday', but there might be some circumstances in which you could use 'when it was'.

Comment: I've edited my question. The context is when I want to explain some details about past, like tell someone what I used to do, to eat and things like that.

Comment: Your birthday is one day every year. Do you mean 'when I was aged six'?

Comment: "On my sixth birthday..."?

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey yes, I meant something like that. I used this phrase in one sentence in a text, describing my childhood. Like, what did I eat _when it was my birthday_? What did I do on Christmas? In fact, I used _on_ in other sentences, but I thought these two grammatical constructions are equal in what they mean.

Comment: If you don't have a specific birthday in mind, maybe you could say: "... when**ever** it was my birthday ... ."

Comment: Sometimes people eat and drink things to celebrate their birthday, **on** their birthday.

Comment: Yes, that is one context in which you _could_ say 'when it  was my birthday', but 'on my birthday' would be more usual.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you so much! I was in doubt if it is a good fit, but my friend told it is grammatically incorrect (or more precisely: illiterate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Grammatically correct?** Yes.

**Appropriate?** "When it was" is not generally used to refer to singular or repeated points in time such a birthdays. It is not typically how one would phrase a sentence related to past events.

The phrase **On [Event/Time/Date]** is a much more common construct in this case.

> I like to eat chocolate cake **on** my birthday.

> **On** my birthday my family would always go to see dinosaurs at the museum.

> I like to go to the water park **on** Thursdays when the entry fee is only $20.

**When it was** is more often used for persistent conditions, rather than singular points in time.

> Over the summer my car only looked clean **when it was** raining.

> As directed, I only turned the machine on **when it was** less than 10C outside.

> The monsters could only feed their young **when it was** dark.

Comment: Very illuminating answer. Thank you!